# Check to make sure data from Column A is not in Column B and Column B data is not in Column A data

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, exists

I have a table called FAILURE with three columns 'PROBLEM','FAILURE','SOLUTION'. I want to check and make sure each column has the correct data and NOT the data of either of the other columns.  IF a column contains data from one of the other columns, then I want to write "incorrect problem, failure or solution", depending on the column the incorrect data is in.

| Problem | Failure | Solution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bad Drive | No Failure | Fixed Drive |
| Bad Light | Damage | Replaced Light |

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM Failure
Where ProblemID <> SolutionID
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Failure
WHERE SolutionID=ProblemID
and
ProblemID=FailureID
```

Nothing is working and I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Problem NVARCHAR(50), Failure NVARCHAR(50), Solution NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Table (Problem, Failure, Solution) VALUES
('Bad Drive', 'No Failure','Fixed Drive'),
('Bad Light', 'Damage', 'Replaced Light'),
('Damage', 'Replaced Light', 'Bad Light');

SELECT *
  FROM @Table t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table t2
      ON t1.Problem = t2.Failure
```

Here we're doing a self `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The result set is showing where rows have matches in between `Problem` and `Failure`. 'Damage' exists in both the Problem and Failure columns.

You can use this technique for as many columns as you'd like.

Comment: I only have 1 table and that's the Failure table. I don't have another table.  The columns are problem, failure, solution.  I want to check to make sure the data from ex.( failure column is not in problem column).  If data is in the wrong column then I want to print "Incorrect data"

Comment: You can join to a single table as many times as you like. You do not have to join to a different table.

Comment: @stondd123 It's called a self-join